# Acceso API Kubernetes con otros users

Tags: kubernetes

He instalado Kubernetes en Centos con un usuario "x". Mi consulta es como puedo hacer para que el server no me rechace intentando usar kubectl con otros usuarios alternativos.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

si te ayuda tenes que hacerlo con RBAC. Podes asisgnarle un Rol al usuario y después hacerle un Rolebinding para unir el Rol al usuario que vos queres. Acá vas a encontrar ejemplos https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/ Espero que te de un comienzo!. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias¡¡!!!!!!